# Not usual vertical alignment between \partial symbol and command \frac

Tags: math-mode, symbols, fractions, mathtools, mtpro

Starting from this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% New \partial
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{nxlmi}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{nxlmi}{m}{it}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{nxlmi}{m}{it}{
  <-6.3>    nxlmi05
  <6.3-8.6> nxlmi07
  <8.6->    nxlmi0
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{nxlmi}{b}{it}{
  <-6.3>    nxlbmi05
  <6.3-8.6> nxlbmi07
  <8.6->    nxlbmi0
}{}
\renewcommand{\partial}{{\text{\usefont{U}{nxlmi}{m}{it}\symbol{64}}\mspace{1mu}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
H_0(x)=\int_{a}^{x} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_{0}, y_{0}(z), y'_{0}(z))\,dz 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
H_1(x)=\int_{a}^{x} \frac{\partial f^{\mathclap{0}}}{\partial y}(x_{0}, y_{0}(z), y'_{0}(z))\,dz 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
H_2(x)=\int_{a}^{x} \frac{\partial f^{\mathbin{0}}}{\partial y}(x_{0}, y_{0}(z), y'_{0}(z))\,dz 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac d{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}(x,y_{0}(x),y'_{0}(x))\right)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y_{0}(x),y'_{0}(x))=0.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{aligned}
\overline{A}'&=\overline{A}+\overline\nabla f \\
\varphi'&=\varphi  -\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\\
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I have seen that with different commands (see the equation `(2)`, `(3)`) there is a bad alignment using `mtpro2` basic version, `\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}`, (it is also can be replaced with `\usepackage{newtxmath}`)
between the symbols `\partial` into the command `\frac`.
In fact it is possible to see that into the equation `(4)`,
the vertical alignment (vertical green line) is very nice but in the other
equations I have a bad vertical alignment.

[image]

I have a suspect that the apex `'` used to write `\partial y^{'}`, it creates a perfect vertical alignment among `\partial f` and `\partial y^{'}`.

Seems strange that some fractions have a better alignment, but there is an little horizontal space between `\partial` and `f`. Why?

[image]

- Is it a problem of `\partial` symbol or this situation is normal?
- How can I fix automatically the problem?

Comment: In a fraction, the numerator and denominator are by default centered horizontally, so unless both are exactly the same width, the leading edges will not align directly above one another.  The italic *f* is wider than many other letters, since the box that encloses it starts at the lower left.  For this letter, which has a large gap between the left edge of its box and the point at which it crosses the baseline, it is often suggested that it be preceded by a negative thin space (`\!`) to close up the gap.  But that still may not make the leading edges align.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Very nice comment.